# How to read every single file in a directory using foreach perl

Tags: perl

im trying to make a script on reading all of the files inside a directory but it seems i cant.... the only thing i can is to list the names of the file inside the directory.So is there a way for me to list it ?
(Kinda new to perl and linux :U)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#locate directories

my $DIR = "/home/aimanhalim/LOG";
opendir(DIR, $DIR) or die $!;

#open Directory and read all the file.

while (my $DIR = readdir(DIR)) {print "$DIR\n";}


exit;
```

Comment: are you having problems reading the files once you find them?  or not finding all the files?  show some example files and data and what output you are trying to get?

Comment: my problem is reading the contents of each individual file... I found the file and it has list it (only the name of the files not the content).

Comment: actually you aren't doing anything with the files in this dir. please let us know what you want to do.

Comment: the problem is that i want to read the contents of each individual files in a directory. So far the one i have done is listing out the file that is inside the directory.

Comment: @DreamMember first you should change the variable Name in your while-loop `my $DIR` into `my $file`, because it shows you each file, not the dir (additionally you already declared `my $DIR` some lines above).
in your while-block, where you already print each file, you can just proceed with your logic for each file. just use a filehandle: https://perldoc.perl.org/FileHandle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have files that can be read line-by-line, as the directory name indicates log files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $DIR = '/home/aimanhalim/LOG';
chdir $DIR;
opendir my $dh, $DIR;
while (my $entry = readdir $dh) {
    next if $entry =~ /^[.]/; # skip the '.' and '..' entries and hidden files
    if (-f $entry) { # skip entries that are not files
        open my $fh, '<', $entry;
        while (my $line = $fh->getline) {
            # do something with the content
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to read directories recursively, perhaps switch over to [Path::Tiny](http://Path::Tiny).

Comment: (need full path to open file as `readdir` returns only the entryname, or chdir)

Comment: the script u given to me doesnt have any problem whatsoever... but when i try to run the script.. it seems that the output doesnt appear .. is it because my files cant be read by line ?? since my file is a log extension and the content of the files are  top (showing the cpu information)

Comment: There is no output. You asked how to **read** files, which this program does.