# How to create a loop to send the finished files into a diffrent directory (CLOSED)

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

So I have create a script where it will execute an insert statement into table "Top" for each file . so the problem i having now is how do i create a script to send the completed (the one that has already successfully insert data into the table ) file to a directory.

I just show the important line :U

Im still new so please bear with my stupidity Q_Q

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use DBI;    
use strict;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;


our $DIR="/home/aimanhalim/LOG";
our $FILENAME_REGEX = "server_performance_";
# mariaDB config hash
our %db_config = ( "username"=>"root", "password"=> "", "db"=>"Top_Data", "ip" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "3306");
main();

exit;

..............................................................................
 my ($result) = insert_record($dataRef,\%db_config);

      #
      # close file
      close($file_hndlr);
      #
      # move file to DONE dir
      #
      # continue until file completed
      last;
   }

..............................................................................

sub insert_record(){

 my($data,$db_config)=@_;
 my $result = -1; # -1 fail;  0 - succ

  # connect to db
  # connect to MySQL database
  my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=".$db_config->{'db'}.";host=".$db_config->{'ip'}.";port=".$db_config->{'port'};
my $username = $db_config->{'username'};
my $password = $db_config->{'password'};

my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;

print "We Have Successfully Connected To The Database \n";

..............................................................................

  # execute insert
  my $sql = 'insert into Top(Load_Average, CPU_User, CPU_ID, CPU_System, CPU_Waiting, Memory_Total, Memory_Used, Swap_Total, Swap_Available) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

  my @param_bind = (); 

  my $stmt =$dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Its A Fail" . $dbh->errstr();
  $param_bind[0] = $data->{'Average_Load'}->{'List_1'};
  $param_bind[1] = $data->{'Cpu_List'}->{'User'};
  $param_bind[2] = $data->{'Cpu_List'}->{'ID'};
  $param_bind[3] = $data->{'Cpu_List'}->{'System'};
  $param_bind[4] = $data->{'Cpu_List'}->{'Waiting'};
  $param_bind[5] = $data->{'Memory_List'}->{'Total'};
  $param_bind[6] = $data->{'Memory_List'}->{'Used'};
  $param_bind[7] = $data->{'Swap_List'}->{'Total'};
  $param_bind[8] = $data->{'Swap_List'}->{'Available'};
  $stmt->execute(@param_bind);

  $stmt->finish();
    print "The Data Has Been Inserted Successfully\n";
  $result = 0;
  return($result);


  # commit
  $dbh->commit();
  # return succ / if fail rollback and return fail
  $dbh->disconnect();


}



exit;
```

Comment: Previous posts in this problem series: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57351361 https://stackoverflow.com/q/57470682 Normally I wouldn't point them out because they are evident from the account history, but here's an account switch involved. If you wish to, the accounts can be merged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: thats reading :U im asking how do i move the files "after" the script has done inserted into MySQL ...

Answer (score 1):

See [`move` in File::Copy](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy#move).

```
use File::Copy qw(move);
⋮
move($entry, $DONE_directory) or
    warn "Could not move file '$entry' into '$DONE_directory': $!";
```

You could also choose to abort the program right away when moving fails, simply replace [`warn`](http://p3rl.org/warn) with [`die`](http://p3rl.org/die).

The loop is the `while` loop as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57356096/46395

Comment: i tried it but it only move 1 file at a time per execution

Answer (score 1):

> I just show the important line

Actually, I think you've shown us the unimportant lines. You've shown us the bits that you know how to do, not the bits that you're having trouble with.

> the problem i having now is how do i create a script to send the completed (the one that has already successfully insert data into the table ) file to a directory.

You don't show us any of the code that deals with files. I assume that you're opening a file and using its contents to populate the `$dataRef` variable. Once you have finished processing that data, you can simply use [the `move()` function from File::Copy](https://perldoc.pl/File::Copy#move) to move your file.

Comment: my bad Q_Q  i feel like thats the important in the script sorry again ... i used "move" but  it only move 1 file per execution ..

Comment: @MiteMiteKyle: *it only move 1 file per execution* Yes, that's how it works. But why is that a problem? Just move each individual file after you've finished with it.

Comment: but my lecturer wants it to execute only once until all files are inside Done directory